# Sorting Multi-Dimensional Arrays in PHP 5

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

First, please excuse me if this is not clear.  English is not my first language, though I have tried very hard to make this as intelligible as possible.  I am having trouble sorting a multi-dimensional array in PHP.  I have reviewed the various array functions on php.net and w3schools, but am still having difficulty.

I have a multi-dimensional array in this form:

```
    $test_array[$counter]['post_id']
    $test_array[$counter]['votecount']
    $test_array[$counter]['content']
```

I am trying to sort the array by votecount, so that the post id with the highest votecount is first and then descends from there.  I want to get it into a form such as below:

```
Votes: 10
Post ID:  4
Content: hhgjhg

Votes: 7
Post ID:  26
Content: fhghg

Votes: 6
Post ID:  15
Content: ytryrd
```

Answer (score 1):

Use usort function http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Answer (score 0):

I know it has something to do with this function call.  I am also having the same sort of problem, but I think my code is wrong with my array.  Look into this function and maybe it will help you. This is added with your array code when the script is processed.

```
function compare($x, $y)
{
    if ($x[1] == $y[1])
    {
        retun 0;
    }
        else if ($x[1] < $y[1])
        {
            return -1;
        }
            else
            {
                return 1;
            }
}

uasort($products, 'compare');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
function custom_sorting($a, $b)
{
    if ($a['votecount'] == $b['votecount']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['votecount'] > $b['votecount']) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($test_array, "custom_sorting");
```

Answer (score 0):

Working Example

```
function custom_sorting($a, $b)
{
    if ($a['votecount'] == $b['votecount']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['votecount'] > $b['votecount']) ? -1 : 1;
}

 $counter = 0;
 $test_array[$counter]['post_id'] = 1;
 $test_array[$counter]['votecount'] = 15;
 $test_array[$counter]['content'] = "1-15";

 $counter = 1;
 $test_array[$counter]['post_id'] = 2;
 $test_array[$counter]['votecount'] = 18;
 $test_array[$counter]['content'] = "2-18";

  $counter = 2;
 $test_array[$counter]['post_id'] = 3;
 $test_array[$counter]['votecount'] = 10;
 $test_array[$counter]['content'] = "3-10";

usort($test_array, "custom_sorting");

print_r($test_array);
```